# How to access onKeyDown handler of material-ui-pickers datepicker keyboard icon?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, onkeydown

I have a Material table with rows with [material-ui-pickers datepicker](https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/api/datepicker) components in the last column.
[image]

I need to add a new row to the table on tab key press when the focus is on datepicker keyboard icon. For this I think it is needed to access `onKeyDown` handler of datepicker keyboard icon.

> How to access `onKeyDown` handler of datepicker keyboard icon?

I have added an [issue](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers/issues/760) to the material-ui-pickers git repo regarding this.

---

I tried to adding the `onKeyDown` handler to the `DatePicker` component. But it will cause to add a new row in both occasions, first tab key press while the focus is on date string and second tab key press while the focus is on the icon.

```
<DatePicker
    id={id}
    keyboard
    ...
    onKeyDown={(e, index) => {
        if (e.keyCode === 9 && this.props.itemData.rows.length - 1 === index) {
            console.log('Tab key pressed');
            this.props.addNewItemDataRow();
        }
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `KeyboardIconProps`

```
<DatePicker
  KeyboardIconProps={{
    onKeyDown: () => console.log('hey') 
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the more recent versions of `DatePicker` (v6.10.1 in this case) [DatePicker API](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/)

We can use `SlotProps`:

```
<DatePicker
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      onKeyDown: (event) => console.log('Key pressed', event.key),
    },
  }}
/>
```